# Angular 2 ngStyle cannot bind font-family start with a number

Tags: javascript, css, angular, font-family, ng-style

I have tried to bind dynamic font-family to text. But I face a problem that a font name start with a number cannot be bind to DOM element. I've done a lot of research but I cannot find why it happens.

Template:

```
<h2 [style.font-family]="font">Hello {{name}}</h2>
```

Component class:

```
constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.font = '28 Days Later';
}
```

With font "Arial", DOM generate fine:
[image]

But, it seems to ignore generating font "28 Days Later"
[image]

Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nq9Haqrumk38eE7B1G43?p=preview)

I appreciate any suggestion, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just use your font like this:

```
 this.font = "'28 Days Later'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found the reason why it happens. A font-family with text only "Arial", it can work without ' '. But font-family start with a number we must use ' ' to wrap it.